# Transferring json object from a cron job

Tags: php, javascript, json, cron

I've a complex php cron job that retrieve data from an external webpage and join all the information in one variable that is encoded in json. The whole process is very slow and takes a lot of time.

The point is that I need to retrieve the json object from my index page, but I don't want to load all the script because it will take too long to execute. What I've been doing is tell the cron job to create a new file and write the json object and I've been retrieving the information from that file.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient/simple way to transfer this information without having to create a new file or executing the script 'manually'. I've heard that you can send information using CURL, the truth is that I've never used this technique before, so dunno if it would be useful in this situation.

Comment: You could store it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common issue.  Long running tasks shouldn't be executed on page load because it impacts ux.  having your time intensive php script running as cron job is a great solution. 
Perhaps using a db would be easier still.  You can easily using [sqlite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) or a "full fledged" rdbms to store your data (like mysql or postregs).  it could be something like:

time intesive php script is running on cronjob every x minutes.  Saves data to your db instead of a file.

When user requests index page it sends ajax request to another php script.  The php script looks for data in your db and returns it to your user if it exists.